# D3.js : How to read data from JSON in Grouped Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv, d3.js

I am working on [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) where I am exploring each and every aspects of D3. While Exploring [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) I can across to read file through JSON (not via CSV).

If you can see in [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) they are using [data.csv](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051#data.csv)

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64
Years,65 Years and Over
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
TX,2027307,3277946,1420518,2454721,7017731,5656528,2472223
NY,1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,5355235,5120254,2607672
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
PA,737462,1345341,679201,1203944,3157759,3414001,1910571
```

I want to build the same graph but with JSON file. **How can I convert this CSV file to JSON file and generate the same graph?** please help.

**EDIT**

I customize this graph accoring to my Need. Here is my data.csv

```
State,Orders,Abandoned
0,300,500
1,400,600
2,500,700
3,600,800
4,700,900
5,800,1000
6,900,1100
7,1000,1200
8,700,900
9,600,700
10,550,750
```

So here I have hard coded all the values, and graph is coming out in a nice format.

Now I am writing a web services using JAXB to send same data using JSON format.

```
{
"ordernumbertrack": [
{
  "state":1,
  "noOfCancellation": "12",
  "noOfOrder": "30"
},
{
  "state":2,
  "noOfCancellation": "7",
  "noOfOrder": "15"
},
{
  "state":3,
  "noOfCancellation": "15",
  "noOfOrder": "35"
},
{
  "state":4,
  "noOfCancellation": "5",
  "noOfOrder": "18"
},
{
  "state":5,
  "noOfCancellation": "10",
  "noOfOrder": "55"
},
{
  "state":6,
  "noOfCancellation": "8",
  "noOfOrder": "45"
},
{
  "state":7,
  "noOfCancellation": "5",
  "noOfOrder": "20"
},
{
  "state":8,
  "noOfCancellation": "6",
  "noOfOrder": "30"
},
{
  "state":9,
  "noOfCancellation": "4",
  "noOfOrder": "22"
},
{
  "state":10,
  "noOfCancellation": "17",
  "noOfOrder": "40"
},
{
  "state":11,
  "noOfCancellation": "2",
  "noOfOrder": "14"
},
{
  "state":12,
  "noOfCancellation": "5",
  "noOfOrder": "18"
}
]
}
```

How can I parse it now ?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which form you store the data. d3 works with arrays and objects, not JSON or CSV. So it makes no difference at all *where* the data came from. No need to convert the CSV file to a JSON file.

Comment: I am writing a web services to send json data, then how it will work?

Comment: suppose I am generating this JSON -> {"ordernumbertrack": [{noOfCancellation": "12",noOfOrder": "30"},{noOfCancellation": "7","noOfOrder": "15"},{"noOfCancellation":"15","noOfOrder": "35"}]}

Comment: That's a different issue then. Do you literally just want to covert this one CSV example to JSON? Either you open up a text editor and write the file manually or you use your favorite scripting language to parse the file, convert the data to JSON and save it to a file. Not sure what kind of answer you expect?

Comment: I don't understand, what does the JSON posted in the comment have to do with the rest of your question?

Comment: ok it was my mistake to not write a proper question, actually I am trying to show noOfOrders and noOfCancellation with this graph. I am writing web services to send those details to my D3 graph. But I am not able to parse the data

Comment: Just for the purpose of reading data through JSON in group chart, I asked that question. If I know, I can make my JSON according to this graph.

Comment: Ok @FelixKling I updated my question with my requirment. Please check it again

Comment: You should probably also post the code you used to parse and process the JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling, I haven't tried with JSON, I am using the same code as giving in [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051#index.html) example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55304/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I created Grouped Bar Chart using JSON data. I have written web services which will send JSON data to D3.

My JSON is same as above I posted in Question

Only the change I have done in D3 is ..

```
d3.json("rooturi/rest/ordernumbertracks", function(error, data) {
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data.ordernumbertrack[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "state";
});

data.ordernumbertrack.forEach(function(d) {
  d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
});

x0.domain(data.ordernumbertrack.map(function(d) { return d.state; }));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.ordernumbertrack, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("");

var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data.ordernumbertrack)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.state) + ",0)"; });
```

I can't expect It is as simple as that :)

Comment: Awesome! This helped me