# grouped bar chart from JSON data instead of CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I am trying to re-create the Grouped Bar Chart example but instead of using CSV I would prefer JSON data:

```
var data = [
  {
    "State": "CA",
    "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
    "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
    "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
    "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
    "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
    "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
    "65 Years and Over": 4114496
  },
  {
    "State": "TX",
    "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
    "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,
    "14 to 17 Years": 1420518,
    "18 to 24 Years": 2454721,
    "25 to 44 Years": 7017731,
    "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
    "65 Years and Over": 2472223
  },
  {
    "State": "NY",
    "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
    "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,
    "14 to 17 Years": 1058031,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1999120,
    "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
    "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
    "65 Years and Over": 2607672
  },
  {
    "State": "FL",
    "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
    "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
    "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
    "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
    "65 Years and Over": 3187797
  },
  {
    "State": "IL",
    "Under 5 Years": 894368,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
    "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
    "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
    "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
    "65 Years and Over": 1575308
  },
  {
    "State": "PA",
    "Under 5 Years": 737462,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
    "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
    "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
    "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
    "65 Years and Over": 1910571
  }
]
```

Here's the example that I am trying to re-create:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Any help will be appreciated I am really a javascript noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by just removing the CSV part of the sample. Here's the static version that linked into a local d3.v3.js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/userName/d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = [
  {
    "State": "CA",
    "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
    "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
    "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
    "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
    "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
    "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
    "65 Years and Over": 4114496
  },
  {
    "State": "TX",
    "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
    "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,
    "14 to 17 Years": 1420518,
    "18 to 24 Years": 2454721,
    "25 to 44 Years": 7017731,
    "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
    "65 Years and Over": 2472223
  },
  {
    "State": "NY",
    "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
    "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,
    "14 to 17 Years": 1058031,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1999120,
    "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
    "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
    "65 Years and Over": 2607672
  },
  {
    "State": "FL",
    "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
    "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
    "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
    "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
    "65 Years and Over": 3187797
  },
  {
    "State": "IL",
    "Under 5 Years": 894368,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
    "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
    "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
    "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
    "65 Years and Over": 1575308
  },
  {
    "State": "PA",
    "Under 5 Years": 737462,
    "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
    "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
    "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
    "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
    "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
    "65 Years and Over": 1910571
  }
]

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JS Bin version: http://jsbin.com/nuyipikaye/edit?html,js,output

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This cab be easily achieved by transposing your array into the required format:

**For conversion you can use:**

```
for(var x in data){
var currData = [];    
for(var y in data[x]){
         currData.push(data[x][y]);
     }
dataArr.push(currData);
}

var tdata = d3.transpose(dataArr);
```

Then use : http://bl.ocks.org/3532324

[D3: Create a grouped bar chart from json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180108/d3-create-a-grouped-bar-chart-from-json-objects)

[Grouped Bar Chart From JSON D3.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828782/grouped-bar-chart-from-json-d3-js)

[D3.js : How to read data from JSON in Grouped Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115053/d3-js-how-to-read-data-from-json-in-grouped-bar-chart)

Comment: I have seen these examples. I have no intention to transform the JSON data into an array as shown in the first link. The other two make little sense to me at this point. I am just getting my feet wet here...

Comment: Ok, then would you like a module to convert JSON to CSV and plug directly into it or stick with a json to grouped chart

Comment: JSON to grouped chart...I think it would be a waste to convert into CSV

Comment: This seems to be working in JS Bin http://jsbin.com/nuyipikaye/edit?js,output but I can't get it to work in static HTML page on my drive when I copy paste the code in.

Comment: Have you included the required JS dependencies on your HTML page ?

Comment: Yeah, I have the <script> src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> tag in

Comment: OK, got it that link doesn't actually work. I just linked in to a local copy of d3.v3.min.js and it worked.